# How to install python34 via yum in redhat

Tags: java, mariadb, redhat, python-3.4, yum

I am trying to install mariadb columnstore api (java wrapper of cpp version) on RHEL 7 and it has dependency on pythong34. The following command can not find the package.

```
sudo yum install python34 or to search sudo yum search python34
```

Other server already have the package installed and search returns the results.

- python34.x86_64 : Version 3 of the Python programming language aka
  Python 3000
- python34-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and header files needed
  for Python 3 development
- python34-libs.x86_64 : Python 3 runtime
  libraries

So far I have tried running

```
yum clean all - to clear cache and all other things update repo..
```

check proxy is same on both server,
yum update

Tried Installing manually by getting rpm but getting the dependency error.

```
python(abi) = 3.4 is needed by mariadb-columnstore-api-1.1.3-1.x86_64
```

Any suggestion would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to install python34, it is part of EPEP repository. So enabled using following link and then was able to to get it via yum.

https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/

Answer (score 0):

Install Python34 via Red Hat Software Collections - these are refreshed tools, db's, etc. that have a separate installation. Can also get from softwarecollections.org.

See [1] to install Python36, but change the command for python34 to *rh-python34* and based on what's listed here [2].

[1] https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/hello-world/#fndtn-python.
[2] https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_software_collections/3/html-single/3.0_release_notes/#sect-RHSCL-Features